# Can I Hide Admin Media Files From WP Media Library For Other Users

Tags: wordpress

Can I Hide Admin Media Files From WP Media Library For Other Users
example : i admin uploaded some files on wp media library and i have some users that can access wp media library and i dont want them to see my files but they can view all other uers files. please share if it is possible

I checked wordpress developer documentation but didnt find anything helpfull for wp media library queries.